# Is it safe to use eval to dynamically call Coffeescript class?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, eval

This is an example of what Im trying to achieve

HTML

`<div data-js-class="Header"></div>`

Coffeescript

```
class Header
  constructor: (@root) ->
    # Header related code here


$('[data-js-class]').each(->
  unless $(this).attr('data-js-loaded') == 'true'
    partial_class = eval($(this).attr('data-js-class'))
    if typeof partial_class != "undefined"
      new partial_class($(this))
      $(this).attr('data-js-loaded', 'true')
)
```

Im not sure if it's entirely safe to use eval() here or if there's a better way to do it? I tried using `window[$(this).attr('data-js-class')]` but it didn't seem to work, maybe due to the way Coffeescript uses closures.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need `eval`, your `window[...]` approach is on the right track. Your problem with using `window` as a namespace is that this:

```
class Header
  constructor: (@root) ->
    # Header related code here
```

becomes (more or less) this:

```
(function() {
  var Header = ...
}).call(this);
```

so you're stuck with a local `Header` variable rather than a global `window.Header`. You could make `Header` global:

```
class @Header
  #---^
  constructor: (@root) ->
    # Header related code here
```

and then your `window[$(this).attr('data-js-class')]` trick will work.

Or better (IMO), create your own namespace for these classes:

```
dynamics = { }
class dynamics.Header
  #...
class dynamics.Footer
  #...
```

and then you can say `new dynamics[$(@).data('js-class')]` and such. Using your own namespace avoids globals and limits you to a small set of specifically cleared classes.